# How to work with excel row-column transformation?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have Many more data to work with, but the scenario is as below pictures

[image: My excel Sheet]

Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 11 lines instead of 5 lines, but for me its close enough ;)

1. Place your cursor in the column where you want your new values
2. Insert the macro somewhere in your VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
3. Execute the macro (<kbd>F5</kbd>)
4. Answer the inputbux with the correct range of your table. In your example: "A2:C9"

---

```
Sub mergeColumns()

    strTable = InputBox("Please enter the range of your table" & vbNewLine & "Example: A1:C4", "Select your table")
    arrTable = Range(strTable)

    For Each cell In arrTable
        i = i + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = cell
    Next

End Sub
```

This is only a prove of concept without tweaks like ScreenUpdating, ErrorHandling or variable declaration.

Comment: @ nixda Thanks for ur attempt. I will have a  try.

Comment: @ nixda you r boss!!!!!

Comment: If this answer solves your question, you could mark it as accepted with the green check mark

Comment: @ nixda What about "Wanted Situation 2"? My actual data are not in the consecutive format rather in double format (e.g. 23.025683,5.3256869 etc.). Any idea?

Comment: As I already said: Use Excels autofill ability to fill up a helper colum (e.g. column D) with ascending numerical values. Select all rows including the helper column and  apply an autofilter. Open the filter dialog for the helper column and choose "Sort largest to smallest". Now your table is upside down. Copy the table to a new place and delete the helper column.